# Google backup service doesn't work

Tags: android, backup

I have problem, else I wouldn't be here.

I am making backup service, but so far, it doesn't work at all. Dunno what problem it is, but when testing (via emulator or via phone, explained way), the data won't be restored. Maybe someone can help?

MyAppsBackupAgent

```
public class AppsBackupAgent extends BackupAgentHelper {

// The name of the SharedPreferences file
static final String PREFS = "uidpref";

// A key to uniquely identify the set of backup data
static final String PREFS_BACKUP_KEY = "uidpref";

// Allocate a helper and add it to the backup agent
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    SharedPreferencesBackupHelper helper = new SharedPreferencesBackupHelper(this, PREFS);
    addHelper(PREFS_BACKUP_KEY, helper);
}

@Override
public void onBackup(ParcelFileDescriptor oldState, BackupDataOutput data,
        ParcelFileDescriptor newState) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onRestore(BackupDataInput data, int appVersionCode,
        ParcelFileDescriptor newState) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Storing happens in mainactivity:

```
SharedPreferences UIDpref = getSharedPreferences("uidpref", 0);
    Log.e("CODE", preferences.getBoolean("IDgenerated", false)+""); 
    BackupManager mBackupManager = new BackupManager(getApplicationContext());

    if(!preferences.getBoolean("IDgenerated", false)){
        SharedPreferences.Editor UIDedit = UIDpref.edit();
        String rnd = GenerateUID(30);
        UIDedit.putString("UID", rnd);
        UIDedit.putBoolean("IDgenerated", true);
        UIDedit.commit();
        mBackupManager.dataChanged();
    }
```

And manifest:

```
<application
    android:backupAgent="ee.elven.katja.AppsBackupAgent"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"  >
```

...

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question but maybe you still need an answer. In your AppsBackupAgent implementation remove `onRestore()` and `onBackup()` methods.

Inherited `BackupAgentHelper` implementations use dispatcher for delivering restore/backup events to registered helper. Your implementation simply disable this work.